# WNetAddConnection2 returns error 86, Net Use Works

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-nt

I try to connect to the `c$` share on an old Windows NT4 SP6 Machine via `WNetAddConnection2`.
This is the Code i used:

```
int main() {
    NETRESOURCE nr;
    std::string remote{"\\\\192.168.178.22\\c$"}
    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
    nr.lpLocalName = NULL;
    nr.lpRemoteName = remote.data();
    nr.lpProvider = NULL;

    auto res = WNetAddConnection2(&nr, "test", "User", NULL);

    if (res == NO_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "Connected\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << res << '\n';
    }
}
```

This just give me the Error Code `86` which stands for:

> The specified network password is not correct.

If i try to mount the Share via `net use` like so:

```
net use \\192.168.178.22\c$ /user:User
```

And give the same Password when prompted for it the connection is successfully made.

Is there something wrong with my Code? Or do i miss something?
Because for me it's strange that the Connection works with `net use` but not with the `WNetAddConnection2` Function.

Comment: You should replace `argv[2]` with `const_cast<char*>(remote.c_str())` or `&remote[0]`, or `remote.data()` in C++17 and later.  And also, you should zero out any fields of the `NETRESOURCE` that you are not using.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry copy paste error =( i also assigned the `remote.data()` to the `lpRemoteName` fixed it in the question

Comment: `\c$` needs to be escaped as `\\c$` in your `remote` string literal

Comment: @RemyLebeau have corrected it thanks again

Comment: But for me it is strange that `net use` works and `WNetAddConnection2` gives me the error with the invalid password.

Comment: You already stated that in the question, you don't need to repeat yourself.